# Cannot change opacity value using Bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, the slider will not change the value, I keep getting "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined`" errors in the browser console.

I just want to change the value of opacity from the initial value of 1, to the value of the slider multiplied by .01.....

my script below:

```
<div id="jpegcam" class="jpegcam_slider" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 1; position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 239px"></div>

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="100"/>
            <script>
                $('#ex1').slider({
                    formater: function(opacity) {
                        return 'Current value: ' + opacity;
                    }
                });
                $('#ex1').on('slide', function(value)
                {
                    $('.jpegcam_slider').style.opacity = (value*.01);
                });
            </script>
```

Been at it for a good hour or two looking up on Google and forums but coming up short...

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

PS I'm using the slider bootstrap js and css plugin from [here](http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're combining jQuery with generic JavaScript.

You need to change this line:

```
$('.jpegcam_slider').style.opacity = (value*.01);
```

To either get the native element object from the jQuery object (using `[0]`):

```
$('.jpegcam_slider')[0].style.opacity = (value*.01);
```

Or use [jQuery's built-in CSS method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('.jpegcam_slider').css({ opacity: value*.01 });
```

See http://try.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com to understand the basics.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it, I cant accept an answer yet for some reason, but will accept yours as you were the first as soon as I am able to.
It fixed the error problem, but it wont change the opacity value of the element i chose.?

Comment: `$('.jpegcam_slider')` is the element(s) you've chosen. If you have more than one element with a class of `.jpegcam_slider`, using jQuery's `.css()` method will change the opacity on all of them. Using the `[0]` method will only target the first element which matches that selector.

Comment: Yup, that's the only element with that classname in the file.. but for some reason wont update the opacity value dynamically.

Comment: What is `value`? Maybe you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pNRAk/

Comment: `value` is what is stated here: http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/

Basically the value of the slider, which ive configured in the `input` element above in the OP

Comment: Nvm I finally got it! I had to put the value of `value` lol! so value.value*.01; my code readability suuucks lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css()` instead since `$('.jpegcam_slider')` is a jQuery object:

```
$('.jpegcam_slider').css('opacity', value*.01);
```